# Pandas data frame with multi index is changing its size after reseting and re indexing

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas data frame with multi index is changing its size when:  I drop NaNs, I reset index calling `reset_index` method and then I create **same** index using `set_index` method

Here is a reproducible example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N_ROWS = 1E8

# Float col will be filled with 80% of NaN values
float_col = pd.Series(np.arange(N_ROWS))
nanidx = float_col.sample(frac=0.8).index
float_col[nanidx] = np.NaN

# Create a datetime col
datetime_col = pd.date_range(start = "1990-09-06", periods = N_ROWS, freq = "S")

# Create a dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({"string_col": "AAAAA", "date_time": datetime_col, "float_col": float_col})

# Create MultiIndex
data = data.set_index(["string_col", "date_time"])
```

After creating data with a multi index, I compute its size

```py
>>> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 100000000 entries, ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1990-09-06 00:00:00')) to ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1993-11-06 09:46:39'))
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Dtype  
---  ------     -----  
 0   float_col  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 4.0+ GB
```

Then I drop NaN values

```py
data_without_na = data[~data["float_col"].isna()]
>>> data_without_na.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 20000000 entries, ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1990-09-06 00:00:00')) to ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1993-11-06 09:46:38'))
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Dtype  
---  ------     -----  
 0   float_col  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 3.0+ GB
```

Note that data frame went down from 4 GB to 3GB. Here I got surprised because
I would have expected that **removing 80%** of the rows would have reduced the size by the same amount.

Now I create a new data frame from  `data_without_na` reseting index and then creating it again

```py
data_without_na_reindexed = data_without_na.reset_index().set_index(["string_col", "date_time"])
```

And this generates a new data frame with different size

```py
>>> data_without_na_reindexed.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 20000000 entries, ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1990-09-06 00:00:00')) to ('AAAAA', Timestamp('1993-11-06 09:46:38'))
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Dtype  
---  ------     -----  
 0   float_col  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 916.5+ MB
```

Now it went down from 3GB to 916 MB. Finally doing some sanity checks

```py
>>> data_without_na_reindexed.equals(data_without_na)
True

>>> data_without_na_reindexed.index.equals(data_without_na.index)
True
```

Why are they differing in their sizes? Are my sanity checks methods enough to compare them?

**OS**: Tested in pandas 1.5.3 and 2.0.3, in python 3.9.16 on Mac

Comment: Can you use info(memory_usage="deep") and check if the usage is different for both?